# Is it okay to access managed object object ID across context this way

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
NSOperationQueue * grabAllImages =[NSOperationQueue new];

self.ImagesCollectedNotIncludingMapImages = [NSMutableArray array];
[[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    Business * businessInThisContext = (Business *)[[BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler managedObjectContext] objectWithID:self.businessDetailed.objectID];//accessing business ID is okay.
```

I should have cached the objectID before the thread. However, I was too lazy. So I just access self.businessDetailed.objectID on a thread that doesn't belong to the managedObjectContext.

Most of the time, no crash.

Recently I got one crash report about it.

I wonder why it's faulty. I mean self.businessDetailed belongs to the mainthread. However, all I did is asking for the .objectID. Can't do that?

Comment: What does the crash report say?

Comment: Crashlitic only says it crash at so and so line